# DynamoDB: Is it possible to retrieve the existent item when using attribute_not_exists?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using `put_item` along with `ConditionExpression='attribute_not_exists(#primary_key)'` to avoid duplicates for some dataset inserts.

Is it possible to allow `put_item` to return the duplicate item without having to perform any other client API call?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [put_item docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html)

> Use **ReturnValues** if you want to get the item attributes as they appeared before they were updated with the PutItem request. For PutItem, the valid values are:
>
> NONE - If ReturnValues is not specified, or if its value is NONE, then nothing is returned. (This setting is the default for ReturnValues.)
>
> ALL_OLD - If PutItem overwrote an attribute name-value pair, then the content of the old item is returned.

I'm not sure how this behavior works when using `attribute_not_exists`, but perhaps it can give you a starting point?

Comment: Using the ReturnValues parameter with the ConditionExpression seems not to change the results / output anyhow, doesn't help me. Wanted to do exactly the same as the OP.